Can a Canada visitor visa be stamped in the US? I applied from Qatar and received approval
I'm an Indian residing in Qatar with a residency permit. The Canada visitor visa was applied from Qatar and is been approved for visa stamping. But currently I'm in the US. Can the visa stamping be done in the US ? If yes, can the passport be couriered to the US VAC?

Yes, it can.
In 2019 my mother had applied for a Canadian TRV along with my father in India. She needed to travel to the USA to visit me, I went with her and we took the approval notice and passport to the NYC VAC. They collected their fees and the passport without any fuss and I was able to pick up her passport the next week. My father had his visa stamped back in India.
Now if you can courier your passport or not, I recommend that you reach out to the VAC to make the appropriate arrangements.
